# Object localization in java

Tags: java

```
public class A {
    public A(List<Object> instances) {
        B b = new B();
        instances.add(b);
    }
}
```

Class c:

```
public class C {
    public  static List<Object> instances = new ArrayList<Object>();
    public C() {
        new A(instances);
    }

    public refresh() {
        for (int h = 0; h < instances.size(); h++) {
            if (instances.get(h). ???? .equals("A") {
                .............
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to get the name of the class A from the list of objects B , automatically , without sending the name of class A as a parameter in class B

Something like that:

```
instances.get(h).getClassLocate()=="A"
```

Because in the list (instances.get(h)) there may be instantiated class b in class d (another)

Comment: So you want if instances.get(h) gives you an instance of class A? Your string comparison wont work here.

Comment: No, I want to know where the object was created (new B ()) ..... B of A or B of D?

Comment: Use instances.get(h).getClass()

Comment: return B class .. i want string "A ", name of class where is created instance of B

Comment: I'm interested to know how this would be possible without sending the name as a parameter in Class B.

Comment: in the constructor of B, can not know where it is called?  ... A or D or E

Comment: If you want the class name as a `String` the [Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) class provides a `getName` and `getSimpleName` method that you may find useful.

Comment: for  class A{  public A(){  B b= new B()}   i want b return string A..... for class D {  public D(){  B b= new B()}   i want b return string D

Comment: `sun.reflect.Reflection.getCallerClass(2);` ?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get the name of the class A from the list of objects B , automatically , without sending the name of class A as a parameter in class B.

You can't. Bad luck. There is nothing in the code you posted that records the site of the call. If you want that, you will have to supply it yourself.